# Python: Sort every row and accumulate weights

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate-functions, cumulative-sum

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{
"A_price": [10, 12, 15],
"B_price": [20, 19, 29],
"C_price": [23, 21, 4],
"D_price": [45, 47, 44],
},
index = ['01-01-2020', '01-02-2020', '01-03-2020']
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
{
"A_weight": [0.1, 0.2, 0.4],
"B_weight": [0.2, 0.5, 0.1],
"C_weight": [0.3, 0.2, 0.1],
"D_weight": [0.4, 0.1, 0.4],
},
index = ['01-01-2020', '01-02-2020', '01-03-2020']
)

out = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
out.columns = out.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
out = out.sort_index(axis=1)
out:
            A               B               C               D
            price   weight  price   weight  price   weight  price   weight
01-01-2020  10      0.1     20      0.2     23      0.3     45      0.4
01-02-2020  12      0.2     19      0.5     21      0.2     47      0.1
01-03-2020  15      0.4     29      0.1     4       0.1     44      0.4
```

What I want to do is calculate the weighted median which is found by sorting the (weight, price) pairs by **price** and then accumulating the weights until the two prices that straddle the 50% cumulative weight point are found.

We then interpolate between those two (weight, price) pairs to find the price at 50% cumulative weight, and then put that price into a new DataFrame.

UPDATE: I changed my dataframe so it is more reflective of what I currently have.

The output I want would be the weighted median for each row. Meaning, for the row of index "01-01-2020" I would expect the median to be the interpolation of price = 23 since when you add the weights across the row, we have 0.1+0.2+0.3 > 0.5. So I would get a dataframe of prices that looks like this:

```
df_prices:
             Price
01-01-2020   23
01-02-2020   19
01-03-2020   29
```

Comment: Will you please add a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: why do we have two columns A and B?

Comment: I updated my question. Essentially the prices in the final dataframe should be the interpolations of the two prices that straddle the 50% weight once they sorted in ascending order, per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
def wmedian(sr):
    df = sr.unstack().sort_values('price')
    return df.loc[df['weight'].cumsum() > 0.5, 'price'].iloc[0]

out2 = out.apply(wmedian, axis=1)
print(out2)

# Output:
01-01-2020    23.0
01-02-2020    19.0
01-03-2020    29.0
dtype: float64
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_median

Comment: I updated my question. I get what you did, however, I would like to do the same but across the row rather than column. I tried editing you code to calculate the weight median across the row but that did not work. What changes need to be done?

Comment: @MathMan99. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: I believe it works on my original dataframe. I will manually check some entries but this may take some time since it is pretty large. I will accept your answer once I verify. Thank you for you help

Comment: @MathMan99. My solution doesn't work?

Comment: Let's say I have two prices that straddle the 50% weight, i.e. one weight is 49% with a price of $12 and the next price of $13 has a weight of 51%. How would I edit your code to interpolate between them?

Comment: So you need to compute the lower/upper weighted median? The current code give you the lower weighted median (`.iloc[0]`)

Comment: Yes. The idea is to get the aggregate price and then have a confidence band. The aggregate price would be the interpolation between the two prices that straddle the 50% weight after being sorted.

Comment: I think I found the problem. Replace `>= 0.5` by `> 0.5`.